# MYSQL Write to a table based on a value in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

As the title suggest I would like to perform an INSERT query to one table based on the value of a column in another table, in an attempt to create a waiting list type system. 
Here is my code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO bookings (username, tourDate, tourTime, tourNumber, guests) 
VALUES ('$username', '$tour_date', '$tour_time', '$tour_num', '$guests')";

$qry = "UPDATE tours
SET available = available-(1+$guests)
WHERE tourNum = '$tour_num'";

"INSERT INTO waitingList (username, tourDate, tourTime, tourNumber, guests) 
VALUES ('$username', '$tour_date', '$tour_time', '$tour_num', '$guests')";
```

In  what I want is:

```
IF
available column in tours does not = 0
THEN
$sql
ELSE 
insert into waitingList
```

'waitingList' is a table which holds identical fields to 'bookings'

Every attempt so far has failed to achieve these results.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

to select value on a table and inserting it in another table you can use this

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column_name1, column_name2)
SELECT column_name1, column_name2 FROM table2
WHERE column_name1 = "x";
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with PDO extension you should try something like this:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:Host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8' , 'yourUserName', 'pw');
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tours");
$rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($rowCount > 0) {
    $stmt = "INSERT INTO bookings 
    (username, tourDate, tourTime, tourNumber, guests) 
    VALUES ('$username', '$tour_date', '$tour_time', '$tour_num', '$guests')";
    $updateStmt = "UPDATE tours
    SET available = available-(1+$guests)
    WHERE tourNum = '$tour_num'";
    $query = $db->exec($stmt);
    $updateQuery = $db->exec($updateStmt);
}
else {
    $stmt = "INSERT INTO waitingList 
    (username, tourDate, tourTime, tourNumber, guests) 
    VALUES ('$username', '$tour_date', '$tour_time', '$tour_num', '$guests')";
    $query = $db->exec($stmt);
}
```

Use of "*" in SELECT queries sometimes is not of good practice, even this way works, you should try to take a more specific field like the primary key of the table.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, attempted your solution but was met with the following error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object 
the line referenced was
'$rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();'

Comment: Yeah made a dumb mistake. Since $db is the new PDO object, you should create the variable $stmt as the object calling the query method, try it now, it should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use innoDB tables and transactions for this.  Also, may I recommend [PDO](http://php.net/pdo)?

**Pseudo Code**

```
qty = guests+1;

INSERT INTO bookings
Begin transaction
Select available from tours where tourNum = :tour_number
If selected available - qty <= 0
    update tours set available to 0 where tourNum = :tour_number
    insert into waiting list
else
    update tours set available to available-qty
endif
Commit Transaction
```